# Unstable Wi-Fi connection and driver crashes

Tags: networking, wifi, opensuse, networkmanager, firmware

I recently moved to openSUSE Tumbleweed on my laptop (XPS 13 7390), and I’m experiencing a lot of issues with my Wi-Fi connection, i.e. it stays connected to the router but for some reason internet access drops randomly every 5–10 minutes and I have to manually restart `NetworkManager` to get it back on, so I’m basically unable to make a video call at this point…

I can say it’s not an issue with the router nor the fiber company, as it works very well on other computers and smartphones. And this behavior happens with whatever Wi-Fi I'm connected to (home, work, coffee shop). Also, I believe it could be related to some Tumbleweed upgrade as it didn’t happen before, but I’m not sure how to check this hypothesis.

Here are a few logs of what happens when the connection drops but it is still connected to the router:

```
❯ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.13 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.13 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +2 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3052ms
pipe 2
```

```
❯ sudo systemctl status NetworkManager
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-02-01 10:04:09 EST; 1h 52min ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 17071 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 4915)
        CPU: 6.885s
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─17071 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Feb 01 11:49:15 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[17071]: <info>  [1706806155.5992] device (wlp58s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 01 11:49:15 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[17071]: <info>  [1706806155.5998] dhcp4 (wlp58s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Feb 01 11:49:19 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[17071]: <info>  [1706806159.0952] dhcp4 (wlp58s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.13
Feb 01 11:49:19 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[17071]: <info>  [1706806159.0957] policy: set 'ORBI49' (wlp58s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Feb 01 11:49:19 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[17071]: <info>  [1706806159.2476] device (wlp58s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 01 11:49:19 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[17071]: <info>  [1706806159.4548] device (wlp58s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 01 11:49:19 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[17071]: <info>  [1706806159.4549] device (wlp58s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 01 11:49:19 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[17071]: <info>  [1706806159.4551] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Feb 01 11:49:19 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[17071]: <info>  [1706806159.4560] device (wlp58s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Feb 01 11:49:19 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[17071]: <info>  [1706806159.4564] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
```

```
❯ sudo iwconfig
[sudo] password for root: 
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp58s0   IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"ORBI49"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.24 GHz  Access Point: 44:A5:6E:61:87:50   
          Bit Rate=234 Mb/s   Tx-Power=30 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=61/70  Signal level=-49 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:41   Missed beacon:0

enp57s0u1u1  no wireless extensions.
```

```
❯ ifconfig 
enp57s0u1u1 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:E0:4C:68:5E:61  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:200714 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:200714 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:97137360 (92.6 MiB)  TX bytes:97137360 (92.6 MiB)

wlp58s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:5B:D8:8F:6F:3B  
          inet addr:192.168.1.13  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7ec4:69ab:9503:1ee2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1919271 errors:0 dropped:1972 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:773399 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1982903871 (1.8 GiB)  TX bytes:160691846 (153.2 MiB)
```

```
❯ lspci | grep Network
3a:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
```

When both the connection to internet and to the router drop:

```
❯ ping 8.8.8.8
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
```

```
❯ sudo iwconfig
[sudo] password for root:
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp58s0   IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=30 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
```

```
❯ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5473 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5473 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1535037 (1.4 MiB)  TX bytes:1535037 (1.4 MiB)
```

```
❯ sudo systemctl status NetworkManager
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-03-19 13:48:51 EDT; 1min 47s ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 18540 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 4915)
        CPU: 7.043s
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─18540 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Mar 19 13:49:12 dell-tumbleweed NetworkManager[18540]: <error> [1710870552.0698] device (wlp58s0): Couldn't initialize supplicant interface: Timeout was reached
Mar 19 13:49:22 dell-tumbleweed NetworkManager[18540]: <warn>  [1710870562.0632] device (wlp58s0): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#2).
Mar 19 13:49:27 dell-tumbleweed NetworkManager[18540]: <error> [1710870567.1085] device (wlp58s0): Couldn't initialize supplicant interface: Timeout was reached
Mar 19 13:49:37 dell-tumbleweed NetworkManager[18540]: <warn>  [1710870577.0666] device (wlp58s0): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#3).
Mar 19 13:49:42 dell-tumbleweed NetworkManager[18540]: <error> [1710870582.0699] device (wlp58s0): Couldn't initialize supplicant interface: Timeout was reached
Mar 19 13:49:52 dell-tumbleweed NetworkManager[18540]: <warn>  [1710870592.0672] device (wlp58s0): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#4).
Mar 19 13:49:57 dell-tumbleweed NetworkManager[18540]: <error> [1710870597.0699] device (wlp58s0): Couldn't initialize supplicant interface: Timeout was reached
Mar 19 13:50:07 dell-tumbleweed NetworkManager[18540]: <warn>  [1710870607.0666] device (wlp58s0): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#5).
Mar 19 13:50:12 dell-tumbleweed NetworkManager[18540]: <error> [1710870612.0699] device (wlp58s0): Couldn't initialize supplicant interface: Timeout was reached
Mar 19 13:50:12 dell-tumbleweed NetworkManager[18540]: <info>  [1710870612.0699] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface keeps failing, giving up
```

The Qualcomm Atheros Firmware is installed and up to date:
[image]
[image]

Not sure if that’s related, but I also experience complete system crashes at random, which seem to be related to the `ath10k` driver. Here are a some truncated kernel logs (because of the number of limited characters):

```
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  </TASK>
Mar 07 16:29:23 dell-tumbleweed kernel: rfkill: input handler disabled
Mar 07 16:29:24 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Mar 07 16:29:24 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Mar 07 16:29:24 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
Mar 07 16:29:24 dell-tumbleweed kernel: r8152 4-1.1:1.0 enp57s0u1u1: carrier on
Mar 07 16:29:24 dell-tumbleweed kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: wmi command 16387 timeout, restarting hardware
Mar 07 16:29:24 dell-tumbleweed kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to set rfkill enable param 0: -11
Mar 07 16:29:24 dell-tumbleweed kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: wmi command 20488 timeout, restarting hardware
Mar 07 16:29:24 dell-tumbleweed kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: already restarting
Mar 07 16:29:24 dell-tumbleweed kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to set vdev 1 chainmask 0x3, nss 2: -11
Mar 07 16:29:24 dell-tumbleweed kernel: softirq: huh, entered softirq 3 NET_RX 00000000b12ddd13 with preempt_count 00000100, exited with 00000000?
Mar 07 16:29:24 dell-tumbleweed kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to receive scan abortion completion: timed out
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to stop scan: -110
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -110
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 804 at net/mac80211/scan.c:412 __ieee80211_scan_completed+0x308/0x320 [mac80211]
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Modules linked in: rfcomm snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer snd_seq snd_seq_device af_packet r8153_ecm cdc_ether usbnet cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg nft_fib_inet nft_fib_ipv4 nft_fib_ipv6 nft_fib >
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  snd_intel_dspcfg libarc4 snd_intel_sdw_acpi intel_tcc_cooling dell_rbtn spi_nor snd_hda_codec x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp mtd intel_rapl_msr cfg80211 snd_hda_core processor_thermal_devic>
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  acpi_thermal_rel ac acpi_pad nvme_fabrics fuse configfs efi_pstore dmi_sysfs ip_tables x_tables usbhid crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul polyval_clmulni polyval_generic gf128mul ghash_clmulni_intel sh>
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 804 Comm: kworker/u16:16 Tainted: G        W          6.7.7-1-default #1 openSUSE Tumbleweed e2e885433d1fe5aad464ce82298227fba6f98fab
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Hardware name: Dell Inc. Latitude 7400/07WDVW, BIOS 1.28.0 11/03/2023
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Workqueue: events_unbound cfg80211_wiphy_work [cfg80211]
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: RIP: 0010:__ieee80211_scan_completed+0x308/0x320 [mac80211]
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Code: 0a 00 48 85 c0 74 0c 48 8b 78 08 48 89 ee e8 3f 24 04 00 65 ff 0d 90 5e 60 3e 0f 85 b1 fe ff ff 0f 1f 44 00 00 e9 a7 fe ff ff <0f> 0b 48 83 c4 08 5b 5d 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 41 5f c3 cc cc cc cc >
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffac78c0af7da8 EFLAGS: 00010246
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: ffff9e7bc43a0398
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: RDX: ffff9e7bc43a0398 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: ffff9e7bc43a0900
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: RBP: ffff9e7bc43a0900 R08: 745e72736d647564 R09: ffff9e7b81aff500
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: R10: 000000000000000f R11: fefefefefefefeff R12: ffff9e7bc43a0900
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff9e7b8013e605 R15: 0000000000000001
Mar 07 16:29:20 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Mar 07 16:29:20 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Mar 07 16:29:20 dell-tumbleweed kernel: usbcore: registered new device driver r8152-cfgselector
Mar 07 16:29:20 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: using NVM file: qca/nvm_usb_00000302.bin
Mar 07 16:29:20 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Enhanced Setup Synchronous Connection command is advertised, but not supported.
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel: NET: Registered PF_ALG protocol family
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel: r8152-cfgselector 4-1.1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel: r8152 4-1.1:1.0: load rtl8153a-4 v2 02/07/20 successfully
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel: r8152 4-1.1:1.0 eth0: v1.12.13
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver r8153_ecm
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel: r8152 4-1.1:1.0 enp57s0u1u1: renamed from eth0
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel: NET: Registered PF_PACKET protocol family
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel: BUG: scheduling while atomic: issue-generator/1644/0x00000101
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Modules linked in: af_packet r8153_ecm cdc_ether usbnet cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg nft_fib_inet nft_fib_ipv4 nft_fib_ipv6 nft_fib nft_reject_inet nf_reject_ipv4 nf_reject_ipv6 nft_reject>
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  dell_rbtn spi_nor snd_hda_codec x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp mtd intel_rapl_msr cfg80211 snd_hda_core processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy processor_thermal_device snd_hwdep mei_wdt proces>
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  dmi_sysfs ip_tables x_tables usbhid crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul polyval_clmulni polyval_generic gf128mul ghash_clmulni_intel sha512_ssse3 hid_multitouch sha256_ssse3 hid_generic sha1_ssse3 i915 >
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel: CPU: 4 PID: 1644 Comm: issue-generator Not tainted 6.7.7-1-default #1 openSUSE Tumbleweed e2e885433d1fe5aad464ce82298227fba6f98fab
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Hardware name: Dell Inc. Latitude 7400/07WDVW, BIOS 1.28.0 11/03/2023
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Call Trace:
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  <TASK>
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  dump_stack_lvl+0x47/0x60
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  __schedule_bug+0x56/0x70
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  __schedule+0x104f/0x14b0
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ? kmem_cache_alloc_node+0x190/0x390
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ? __mod_timer+0x116/0x370
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  schedule+0x32/0xd0
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  schedule_timeout+0x8b/0x160
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ? __pfx_process_timeout+0x10/0x10
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ath10k_wmi_cmd_send+0x19a/0x1e0 [ath10k_core 6d1e1a1cb123ddb6d778c4e3d92a0f140dae4755]
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ? __pfx_autoremove_wake_function+0x10/0x10
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ath10k_mac_rfkill_enable_radio+0x5d/0xa0 [ath10k_core 6d1e1a1cb123ddb6d778c4e3d92a0f140dae4755]
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ? ath10k_wmi_tlv_parse_alloc.constprop.0+0x23/0xb0 [ath10k_core 6d1e1a1cb123ddb6d778c4e3d92a0f140dae4755]
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ath10k_wmi_tlv_op_rx+0x6a9/0xb10 [ath10k_core 6d1e1a1cb123ddb6d778c4e3d92a0f140dae4755]
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ? ath10k_htt_txrx_compl_task+0x11d2/0x14f0 [ath10k_core 6d1e1a1cb123ddb6d778c4e3d92a0f140dae4755]
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ath10k_htc_rx_completion_handler+0x120/0x170 [ath10k_core 6d1e1a1cb123ddb6d778c4e3d92a0f140dae4755]
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ? __pfx_ath10k_htc_rx_completion_handler+0x10/0x10 [ath10k_core 6d1e1a1cb123ddb6d778c4e3d92a0f140dae4755]
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ath10k_pci_process_rx_cb+0x155/0x1a0 [ath10k_pci c7d57ee248ab6b7236fbaab1828f86065ba55ae2]
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ath10k_ce_per_engine_service+0x5c/0x90 [ath10k_core 6d1e1a1cb123ddb6d778c4e3d92a0f140dae4755]
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ath10k_ce_per_engine_service_any+0x8d/0xa0 [ath10k_core 6d1e1a1cb123ddb6d778c4e3d92a0f140dae4755]
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ath10k_pci_napi_poll+0x4b/0x130 [ath10k_pci c7d57ee248ab6b7236fbaab1828f86065ba55ae2]
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  __napi_poll+0x28/0x1b0
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  net_rx_action+0x296/0x300
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  __do_softirq+0xbf/0x2a5
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  __irq_exit_rcu+0x96/0xb0
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  common_interrupt+0x48/0xa0
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  asm_common_interrupt+0x26/0x40
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel: RIP: 0033:0x55fb09bd5a70
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Code: 48 8d 78 01 e8 81 32 ff ff 48 89 de 48 89 c7 e8 f6 03 fa ff 48 89 c3 48 89 5d 10 e9 4e ff ff ff 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 <48> 85 ff 0f 84 d1 00 00 00 41 54 55 53 48 89 fb eb 34 66 0f 1f >
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel: RSP: 002b:00007fffeb224368 EFLAGS: 00000202
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel: RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 000055fb0b444350 RCX: 000055fb0b444a80
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 000055fb0b4453a0 RDI: 000055fb0b444a80
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel: RBP: 000055fb0b4453c0 R08: 000055fb0b42b010 R09: 0000000000000007
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel: R10: 000055fb0b4453b0 R11: b627c22513797ef4 R12: 000055fb0b444a80
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel: R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 000055fb09c2f7a0 R15: 000055fb0b445330
Mar 07 16:29:21 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  </TASK>
Mar 07 16:29:23 dell-tumbleweed kernel: rfkill: input handler disabled
Mar 07 16:29:24 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Mar 07 16:29:24 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Mar 07 16:29:24 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
Mar 07 16:29:24 dell-tumbleweed kernel: r8152 4-1.1:1.0 enp57s0u1u1: carrier on
Mar 07 16:29:24 dell-tumbleweed kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: wmi command 16387 timeout, restarting hardware
Mar 07 16:29:24 dell-tumbleweed kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to set rfkill enable param 0: -11
Mar 07 16:29:24 dell-tumbleweed kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: wmi command 20488 timeout, restarting hardware
Mar 07 16:29:24 dell-tumbleweed kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: already restarting
Mar 07 16:29:24 dell-tumbleweed kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to set vdev 1 chainmask 0x3, nss 2: -11
Mar 07 16:29:24 dell-tumbleweed kernel: softirq: huh, entered softirq 3 NET_RX 00000000b12ddd13 with preempt_count 00000100, exited with 00000000?
Mar 07 16:29:24 dell-tumbleweed kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to receive scan abortion completion: timed out
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to stop scan: -110
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -110
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 804 at net/mac80211/scan.c:412 __ieee80211_scan_completed+0x308/0x320 [mac80211]
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Modules linked in: rfcomm snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer snd_seq snd_seq_device af_packet r8153_ecm cdc_ether usbnet cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg nft_fib_inet nft_fib_ipv4 nft_fib_ipv6 nft_fib >
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  snd_intel_dspcfg libarc4 snd_intel_sdw_acpi intel_tcc_cooling dell_rbtn spi_nor snd_hda_codec x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp mtd intel_rapl_msr cfg80211 snd_hda_core processor_thermal_devic>
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  acpi_thermal_rel ac acpi_pad nvme_fabrics fuse configfs efi_pstore dmi_sysfs ip_tables x_tables usbhid crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul polyval_clmulni polyval_generic gf128mul ghash_clmulni_intel sh>
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 804 Comm: kworker/u16:16 Tainted: G        W          6.7.7-1-default #1 openSUSE Tumbleweed e2e885433d1fe5aad464ce82298227fba6f98fab
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Hardware name: Dell Inc. Latitude 7400/07WDVW, BIOS 1.28.0 11/03/2023
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Workqueue: events_unbound cfg80211_wiphy_work [cfg80211]
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: RIP: 0010:__ieee80211_scan_completed+0x308/0x320 [mac80211]
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Code: 0a 00 48 85 c0 74 0c 48 8b 78 08 48 89 ee e8 3f 24 04 00 65 ff 0d 90 5e 60 3e 0f 85 b1 fe ff ff 0f 1f 44 00 00 e9 a7 fe ff ff <0f> 0b 48 83 c4 08 5b 5d 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 41 5f c3 cc cc cc cc >
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffac78c0af7da8 EFLAGS: 00010246
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: ffff9e7bc43a0398
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: RDX: ffff9e7bc43a0398 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: ffff9e7bc43a0900
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: RBP: ffff9e7bc43a0900 R08: 745e72736d647564 R09: ffff9e7b81aff500
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: R10: 000000000000000f R11: fefefefefefefeff R12: ffff9e7bc43a0900
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff9e7b8013e605 R15: 0000000000000001
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9e7eec200000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: CR2: 000056300b970070 CR3: 000000010d636006 CR4: 00000000003706f0
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Call Trace:
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  <TASK>
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ? __ieee80211_scan_completed+0x308/0x320 [mac80211 74c03b5fbcd629ee0e490c37f608f5ea2e3ab206]
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ? __warn+0x81/0x130
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ? __ieee80211_scan_completed+0x308/0x320 [mac80211 74c03b5fbcd629ee0e490c37f608f5ea2e3ab206]
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ? report_bug+0x171/0x1a0
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ? handle_bug+0x3c/0x80
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ? exc_invalid_op+0x17/0x70
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ? asm_exc_invalid_op+0x1a/0x20
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ? __ieee80211_scan_completed+0x308/0x320 [mac80211 74c03b5fbcd629ee0e490c37f608f5ea2e3ab206]
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ? finish_task_switch.isra.0+0x94/0x2f0
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ieee80211_scan_work+0x10e/0x530 [mac80211 74c03b5fbcd629ee0e490c37f608f5ea2e3ab206]
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  cfg80211_wiphy_work+0x98/0xc0 [cfg80211 ef514941d3d9bb0bfc8815af8a8a1e7ae6f74b2c]
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  process_one_work+0x165/0x330
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  worker_thread+0x2f5/0x410
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ? __pfx_worker_thread+0x10/0x10
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  kthread+0xe5/0x120
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ret_from_fork+0x31/0x50
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel:  </TASK>
Mar 07 16:29:28 dell-tumbleweed kernel: ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
Mar 07 16:29:29 dell-tumbleweed kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: device successfully recovered
Mar 07 16:29:55 dell-tumbleweed kernel: NOHZ tick-stop error: local softirq work is pending, handler #08!!!
Mar 07 16:30:08 dell-tumbleweed kernel: NOHZ tick-stop error: local softirq work is pending, handler #08!!!
Mar 07 16:30:15 dell-tumbleweed systemd-journald[587]: /var/log/journal/1875b02db71c46278c3455b544a24ae7/user-1000.journal: Journal file uses a different sequence number ID, rotating.
Mar 07 16:30:15 dell-tumbleweed kernel: rfkill: input handler enabled
Mar 07 16:30:19 dell-tumbleweed kernel: wlp58s0: authenticate with 44:a5:6e:61:5b:3b (local address=40:5b:d8:8f:6f:3b)
Mar 07 16:30:19 dell-tumbleweed kernel: wlp58s0: send auth to 44:a5:6e:61:5b:3b (try 1/3)
Mar 07 16:30:19 dell-tumbleweed kernel: wlp58s0: authenticated
Mar 07 16:30:19 dell-tumbleweed kernel: wlp58s0: associate with 44:a5:6e:61:5b:3b (try 1/3)
Mar 07 16:30:19 dell-tumbleweed kernel: wlp58s0: associate with 44:a5:6e:61:5b:3b (try 2/3)
Mar 07 16:30:19 dell-tumbleweed kernel: wlp58s0: RX AssocResp from 44:a5:6e:61:5b:3b (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=2)
Mar 07 16:30:19 dell-tumbleweed kernel: wlp58s0: associated
Mar 07 16:30:19 dell-tumbleweed kernel: block nvme0n1: No UUID available providing old NGUID
Mar 07 16:30:19 dell-tumbleweed kernel: rfkill: input handler disabled
Mar 07 16:31:01 dell-tumbleweed kernel: input: WH-CH510 (AVRCP) as /devices/virtual/input/input26
Mar 07 16:32:25 dell-tumbleweed kernel: usb 1-10: USB disconnect, device number 5
Mar 07 16:32:25 dell-tumbleweed kernel: usb 1-10: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
Mar 07 16:32:25 dell-tumbleweed kernel: usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=e007, bcdDevice= 0.01
Mar 07 16:32:25 dell-tumbleweed kernel: usb 1-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Mar 07 16:32:25 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: using NVM file: qca/nvm_usb_00000302.bin
Mar 07 16:32:26 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Enhanced Setup Synchronous Connection command is advertised, but not supported.
Mar 07 16:32:26 dell-tumbleweed kernel: Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
Mar 07 16:32:51 dell-tumbleweed kernel: input: WH-CH510 (AVRCP) as /devices/virtual/input/input27
Mar 07 16:34:25 dell-tumbleweed kernel: NOHZ tick-stop error: local softirq work is pending, handler #08!!!
Mar 07 16:39:49 dell-tumbleweed kernel: BTRFS info (device nvme0n1p3): qgroup scan completed (inconsistency flag cleared)
```

And here are some non truncated kernel logs: https://0bin.net/paste/pUQ7MJb-#eL5-ZwuSWzrtRAg8800bArlXHF99fYQgTkkPAB3rcc3

Any idea how I could fix this issue?

Comment: You're not showing the condition of the interface when the connection does not appear to work since both iwconfig & iwconfig both suggest it is up & running.  You are also not showing what the routing table is before & during & what the diff is, if any. You could try switching to wicked through `yast2 lan` & see if that helps.

Comment: Also, are you using Bluetooth at the same time (eg: headset for video conference)? If Wifi is in the 2.4GHz band rather than 5GHz band, both share same freqs and interferences can happen (even if this is not supposed to happen).

Comment: Indeed, I'm using a Bluetooth headset at the same time, but the Wi-Fi is at 5Ghz:
`wlp58s0   IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"ORBI49" Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.24 GHz`

Comment: I tried to update the issue with more logs and also some kernel logs about the driver crashes